# Reference a Cell as the Name of a Sheet in Another Workbook

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, importrange

I have ~400 sheets spread through multiple workbooks (on purpose). Each sheet is the scoring for an entry in an award competition.

I have a master scorecard sheet that grabs the score from each sheet, regardless of what workbook it is in. I have been able to set up the formula so, if I hardcode the name of the sheet in some other workbook, it correctly grabs the data:

`=(IMPORTRANGE("LINKtoWORKBOOK","SHEETNAME!CELL"))`

But this requires identifying SHEETNAME in every instance of this formula. I would rather create a single column that lists the names of each sheet, and then for a given row, have that row's formulas all look to the cell with the sheet name.

I've tried using INDIRECT but had no luck. I think I am close:

`=(IMPORTRANGE("LINKtoWORKBOOK",(INDIRECT(CELLwithSHEETname&"!CELLonTHATsheet"))))`

I've tried variations of quotes and moving parenthesis with no luck.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The second argument of IMPORTRANGE should be text value (string) so you can concatenate the sheet name to the cell / range reference. I.E. if `A1` has the sheet name use

```
=IMPORTRANGE("spreadsheet_key",A1&"!A1:Z")
```

NOTES:

`INDIRECT` function can't be used because it returns **a reference** as if it is directly written in the formula, i.e.

```
=A1
```

is the same as

```
=INDIRECT("A1")
```

but IMPORTRANGE requires that the second argument be a text value, so the above will only work when `A1` has something like `A1:Z` or `Sheet1!A1:Z` (without the equal or plus sign)

Arrays can't be used as arguments of IMPORTRANGE. In other words, something like

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IMPORTRANGE("spreadsheet_key",A1:A10))
```

doesn't work. In this case the alternative is to use multiple `IMPORTRANGE`, one for each reference.

Related

- [Using IMPORTRANGE, INDIRECT, and CONCATENATE together](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39259223/1595451)
- [Using IMPORTRANGE as an array formula](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41504050/1595451)
- [ArrayFormula + multiple IMPORTRANGE + QUERY](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48708951/1595451)